# How can I push an array of objects, without changing the data type of the property?

Tags: javascript, loops, object

```
function where(collection, source) {
 var arr = [];

 for (var p in collection) {
    for (var x in source) {
        if (collection[p].hasOwnProperty(x)) {
            if (collection[p][x] === source[x]) {
                arr.push(collection[p]);
                break;
            }
            }
        }
    }
for (var i in arr) {
    if (Object.keys(arr[i]).length < Object.keys(source).length) {
        delete arr[i];
    }
}
  return arr;
  }

where([{ "a": 1, "b": 2 }, { "a": 1 }, { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 2 }], {"a": 1, "b": 2 });
```

The arr.push in the first loop puts the object into the array, but changes the properties so they are no longer strings -  from `"a":1 to a:1.`  I need the quotation marks to be intact around the properties.

Whilst looking for the solution, I came across a tid-bit of information where pushing an object into an array, it just references the object itself, rather than copying it into the array directly.

Anyone here with any ideas? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript objects *only* take strings as properties.

You can verify this by inspecting their types after you've pushed the new object.

```
Object.keys({ "a": 1, "b": 2 })
  .map(prop => typeof prop);
// ["string", "string"]
```

The console shows them without quotes because it is already implied that they are strings.

ES2015 introduces computed properties as an alternative, but their syntax is noticeably different.

```
var str = 'a';
var obj = { [a]: 1 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps create a new object literal right before pushing it to the array?

Something like...

```
if (collection[p][x] === source[x]) {
  var foo = new Object;

  // for all keys and values of collection[p]
  foo[*collection[p] property as string*] = *collection[p] property value*
  ...

  arr.push(foo);

  break;
}
```